# When does Application's onCreate() method get called?

Tags: android-activity, oncreate, application-lifecycle, android

In my Android application, I have a `DefaultApplication` class which extends `android.app.Application`, and in its `onCreate()` I bind some services which will be used by my other Activities in this app.

Also I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens and receives C2DM Messages. When this receiver receives a message when the application is not running, it will fire a dialog which shows the upcoming message and it will start an Activity of my application.

My question is, when I start an activity without any interaction with `DefaultApplication`, will my `DefaultApplication`'s `onCreate()` get called because an Activity of that application has started?

Here are the definition and Manifest of my `DefaultApplication`:

```
public class DefaultApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        doBindService();

    }

    void doBindService() {

        // Establish a connection with the service. We use an explicit
        // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
        // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
        // supporting component replacement by other applications).

        bindService(new Intent(DefaultApplication.this, SocketService.class),
                socketServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(socketServiceConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest looks like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.mypackage.DefaultApplication"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:debuggable="true">
<service android:name="com.mypackage.services.SocketService"></service>
<activity android:name="TestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: yes, it works this, I haven't seen another else...

Comment: I don't unserstand why you extend `Application`? Shouldn't you extend `Activity`?

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS In the rest of my DefaultApplication I store some data and define some methods which are used Application-wide. I copied only a part of it to here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Only the first time.

When Activity is started and application is not loaded, then both `onCreate()` methods will be called.

But for subsequent starts of Activity, the `onCreate()` of application will not be called.

Comment: Not strictly true. [Paul's answer explains a bit more, including a useful link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28498115/383414)

Comment: In my case, onCreate method of application class is only being called when I install the app in mobile, it does not being invoked every time when I kill the app and restart it.

Answer (score 36):

You can find an official answer when `onCreate` is called [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity,
>   service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be
>   sure to call super.onCreate().

Answer (score 20):

Note that if any service is defined to run in other process e.g. with `android:process=` then Application's `onCreate()` will be called again for that process.

For example see [Android Application class method onCreate being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809737/android-application-class-method-oncreate-being-called-multiple-times)