# Using context in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context

How can I get the context in a fragment?

I need to use my database whose constructor takes in the context, but `getApplicationContext()` and `FragmentClass.this` don't work so what can I do?

Database constructor

```
public Database(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1433, accepted):

You can use [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), which returns the activity associated with a `fragment`.
The activity is a `context` *(since `Activity` extends `Context`)*.

Comment: getActivity() can return null if it is called before onAttach of the respective fragment.

Comment: yes so check if it is null before using anything with context

Comment: I was reading this Google blog on memory leaks...http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html . If I use the getActivity() method would the app not be at risk of memory leaks? The blog suggests "Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity" which isn't really possible as getApplicationContext() only works for the Activity class and not the Fragment class.

Comment: A solution for the problem of detached fragments is to store the value of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in an instance variable when the fragment is created and then use that context whenever you want inside the fragment class. That context will survive fragment detachments.

Comment: Instead of passing around the application context, create a static context inside your Application class and initialize it onCreate():
MyApplication.sContext = getApplicationContext();
then you can access it from any activity/fragment without worrying about detachment.

Comment: One thing though. this method is added on API 23 and cannot be used if you are stuck with older APIs. In that case I would refer to the answer by imabox. Besides you kinda want to maintain the backwards compatibility if you work on a serious project. So there's that as well.

Comment: @milaniez: `getActivity` has always been available. It's `getContext` which was added in API 23.

Comment: Why not use getContext() if its the context you are after?

Comment: @EduardKotysh what a beautiful welcome party for memory leak :)

Comment: @Farid If `MyApplication` is holding a static reference to the *application* context, how could that result in a memory leak? I understand that, normally, the `onCreate()` method of `MyApplication` will only be called once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7686586/1617737 .

Comment: @Piovezan Does that create a chance for memory leakage?

Comment: @Prof I haven't been working with Android for years, but I don't think so. If you keep a reference for the application context only (which, as the name implies, lasts for the whole app lifecycle) you are not preventing anything from being garbage-collected sooner (longer? sorry about my English) than it is normally going to. Eduko's suggestion right below mine also seems fine based on the same principle.

Answer (score 138):

To do as the answer above, you can override the `onAttach` method of fragment:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment{
...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend this, as getActivity() returns null if onAttach isn't called yet.

Comment: But, keep in mind, when onAttach() is called, there are no views. So you cannot do anything with views yet!

Comment: @iambox what if `DatabaseHelper` needed a `FragmentActivity` instead of an `Activity`? For example, for an `Adapter`...

Comment: If you store a reference to your activity in `onAttach(Activity activity)` then you should release it in `onDetach()`

Comment: The `onAttach` method has been deprecated, `Overrides deprecated method in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'`

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib [Official docs give no indication it was deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context))

Comment: This is now deprecated in androidx

Answer (score 29):

The easiest and most precise way to get the context of the fragment that I found is to get it directly from the `ViewGroup` when you call `onCreateView` method at least here you are sure not to get null for `getActivity()`:

```
public class Animal extends Fragment { 
  Context thiscontext;
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    thiscontext = container.getContext();
```

Comment: that's the context of the container, I think ... not "this context".

Comment: @AG1 could you please explain why did it crashed your code? This is so far the best solution I've got

Comment: Actually on dialogFragments the container **can** be null. Be carefull!

Comment: This solution should be used in onViewCreated, not  onCreateView.

Answer (score 26):

Always use the [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) method to get the context of your attached activity, but always remember one thing: Fragments are slightly unstable and `getActivity` returns null some times, so for that, always check the [isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method of fragment before getting context by `getActivity()`.

Comment: I would not say that fragments are "slightly unstable", it seems quite normal for getActivity() to return null when the fragment does not belong to an activity. It is assuming that getActivity() "should not return null" (which is wrong) that would make your app (and not the Fragment class) unstable.

Comment: @personne3000 I'd like to hear more. When is a fragment not belonging to an Activity? When is this happening and why? Should we be checking isAdded() in the fragment in order to use getActivity()? Any rule of thumb?

Comment: @Sotti I encourage you to create a new question for this (or look for an existing one), since this specific subject is a little different from the original question. You can have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle for general information. Basically, before onAttach and after onDetach, no activity. And between onAttach and onActivityCreated, the activity's onCreate has not been called yet. When using getActivity(), make sure your activity was already created, and think about what would happen if it was destroyed or your fragment was detached.

Answer (score 25):

The correct way is to use

```
requireContext()
```

and the example

```
ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent),
```

Comment: Context != ApplicationContext

Comment: How `requireContext()` is considered correct when it may throw an exception? I believe it's a harmful way to use.

Comment: @YaMiN, it’s correct because you should be familiar with the lifecycle so you know you are only calling it when it won’t throw an exception. And if you made a mistake about this, you want it to fail fast so you’ll immediately catch your error in testing. You’ll get a more useful exception message than a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 19):

Previously I'm using `onAttach (Activity activity)` to get `context` in `Fragment`

> Problem

The [**`onAttach (Activity activity)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)) method was deprecated in API level 23.

> Solution

Now to get context in  `Fragment` we can use [**`onAttach (Context context)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context))

> **`onAttach (Context context)`**

- Called when a fragment is first attached to its `context`. `onCreate(Bundle)` will be called after this.

> Documentation

```
/**
 * Called when a fragment is first attached to its context.
 * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will be called after this.
 */
@CallSuper
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mCalled = true;
    final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
    if (hostActivity != null) {
        mCalled = false;
        onAttach(hostActivity);
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    private Context mContext;
    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rooView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "THIS IS SAMPLE TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rooView;
    }

}
```

### NOTE

We can also use **`getActivity()`** to get `context` in `Fragments`
but `getActivity()` can return `null` if the your  `fragment` is not currently attached to a parent `activity`,

Comment: Yes, Its good solution but need to be test various cases.

Answer (score 14):

requireContext()  method is the simplest option

```
requireContext()
```

Example

```
MyDatabase(requireContext())
```

Answer (score 12):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context=activity;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also get the context from the `inflater` parameter, when overriding `onCreateView`.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* ... */
        Context context = inflater.getContext();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative approach is:

You can get the context using:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 5):

to get the context inside the Fragment will be possible using [**`getActivity()`**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) :

```
public Database()
{
    this.context = getActivity();
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
}
```

- Be careful, to get the `Activity` associated with the fragment using `getActivity()`, you can use it but is not recommended it will cause memory leaks.

I think a better aproach must be getting the `Activity` from the `onAttach()` method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt be using getActivity in a fragment to get a view unless that view is part of the activity anyway. Why would you inflate a view in a fragment then not even reference anything from it?

Comment: This answer is about something different, you're talking about which view hiearchy to search for views in. `Activity.findViewById` is just a convenience method to search for a view in that activity's registered content view (set through `setContentView`). In your correct example you are calling `View.findViewById`, not `Activity.findViewById`, and you are invoking the method on the *correct* root view. Totally different problem, and obviously you won't be able to find your view in a view hiearchy that doesn't hold that view.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the getActivity() method to get context or
You can use getContext() method .

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);
Context c = root.getContext();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 4):

`getContext()` came in API 23. Replace it with getActivity() everywhere in the code.

See if it fixes the error. Try to use methods which are in between the target and minimun API level, else this error will come in place.

Answer (score 3):

Since API level 23 there is `getContext()` but if you want to support older versions you can use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` while I still recommend using the support version of `Fragment` which is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin you can use `context` directly in fragments. But in some cased you will find an error like

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Context? but Context was expected

for that you can do this

```
val ctx = context ?: return
textViewABC.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, android.R.color.black))
```

Comment: Thanks for availing a Kotlin version, which works fine, however I am trying to get Context for Picasso.get(), with it and it never works, I have tried all i can from samples above as well to get context. At best I get this message -Too many arguments passed... Please help.         val ctx = context ?: return

        Picasso.get(ctx)
                .load(selectedGallery.imageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(galleryImage)

Comment: @Ade In your fragment, try to use "activity!!" instead of "ctx" and let me know it helps or not

Comment: @ KishanSolanki124. Thanks very much for the quick response. I tried your suggestion, with the same result - Not working still. The exact error prompt is - Too many arguments for public open fun get(): Picasso!. This message makes me think, maybe something else is the error?. Gladly though, found a way to move on with my work by using Picasso without getting context. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

In **kotlin** just use `activity` instead of `getActivity()`

Answer (score 2):

`getActivity()` is a child of Context so that should work for you

Answer (score 2):

You have different options:

- If your minSDK <= 21, then you can use `getActivity()`, since this is a `Context`.
- If your minSDK is >=23, then you can use `getContext()`.

If you don't need to support old versions then go with `getContext()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use fragments from **Support Library** -

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

and then override

```
void onAttach (Context context) {
  this.context = context;
}
```

This way you can be sure that context will always be a non-null value.

Answer (score 2):

safe way to get context in fragment

```
if(isAdded){
requireActivit();//this is your context
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to use `getActivity()`. But I think the major confusion of using the `getActivity()` method to get the context here is a null pointer exception.

For this, first check with the `isAdded()` method which will determine whether it's added or not, and then we can use the `getActivity()` to get the context of Activity.

Comment: How is this different from [Ankur Chaudhary's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment/22174744#22174744)?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not need to use globals. The fragment has different notifications, one of them being onActivityCreated. You can get the instance of the activity in this lifecycle event of the fragment.

Then: you can dereference the fragment to get activity, context or applicationcontext as you desire:

`this.getActivity()` will give you the handle to the activity
`this.getContext()` will give you a handle to the context
`this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` will give you the handle to the application context. You should preferably use the application context when passing it on to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getActivity()` or,

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.activity = (CashActivity) context;
    this.money = this.activity.money;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentMenuBinding binding=FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view=binding.getRoot();
        mContext=view.getContext();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can use this:
requireActivity().applicationContext

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      Context context = getActivity.getContext();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need context for using  arrayAdapter IN fragment, when I was using **getActivity** error occurs but when i replace it with **getContext** it works for me

```
listView LV=getView().findViewById(R.id.listOFsensors);
LV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,listSensorType));
```

Answer (score 0):

On you fragment

```
((Name_of_your_Activity) getActivity()).helper
```

On Activity

```
DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside fragment for kotlin sample would help someone

```
textViewStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.red))
```

if you use databinding;

```
bindingView.textViewStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.red))
```

Where bindingView is initialized in **onCreateView** like this

```
private lateinit var bindingView: FragmentBookingHistoryDetailBinding

bindingView = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout_xml, container, false)
```

Answer (score -2):

androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

```
@NonNull
public final android.content.Context requireContext()
```

Return the Context the fragment is currently associated with.

Since:
getActivity and Context can be null, it is good practice to use requireContext() as it can't be null.

Comment: `it is good practice to use requireContext() as it can't be null.` that is nonsense, sure, it can't be null, because it will throw an exception if it is null when using require context. there's also [already an answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60486970/4729721)