# get Context in non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-context

In an android Application, is there any way  to get the context in android in a non-activity class if the activity class name is known?

Comment: pass the context of ur current activity to the java class constructor...

Comment: If your non-activity class is a `Fragment`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment.

Comment: If you want to avoid context passing, then make a class that extends Application class, and inside that define- private static Context appContext; and at onCreate(){ this.appContext =getApplicationContext() ;}, and make public static Context getContext(){ return appContext ;} method that will return the application context and use in onActivity class.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

If your class is non-activity class, and creating an instance of it from the activiy, you can pass an instance of context via constructor of the later as follows:

```
class YourNonActivityClass{

// variable to hold context
private Context context;

//save the context recievied via constructor in a local variable

public YourNonActivityClass(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

}
```

You can create instance of this class from the activity as follows:

```
new YourNonActivityClass(this);
```

Comment: What if I have a static instance of my class, there I have a problem with static contexts. What should I do '

Comment: @MehvishAli could u give a detailed explanation?

Comment: gives a 'this field leaks a context object' warning