# Get the context inside a Java Class

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-context

I have created the following class

```
package com.salvo.weather.android.geolocation;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.salvo.weather.android.entity.CurrentGeolocationEntity;

/**
 * Created by mazzy on 30/05/15.
 */
public class CurrentGeolocation implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private CurrentGeolocationEntity mCurrentGeolocationEntity;

    public CurrentGeolocation() {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity = new CurrentGeolocationEntity();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity.setmLastLocation(LocationServices
                .FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(this.mGoogleApiClient));

        Location mLastLocation = this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity.getmLastLocation();

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity.setmLongitude(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity.setmLatitude(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        } else {
            // TODO: Add toast
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
    }
}
```

and I need to retrieve the context in order to pass it inside the GoogleApiClient. What do you say about? This is a good way? I'm a beginner in Android programming

Comment: Ok I have just found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917968/get-context-in-non-activity-class-android

Comment: What I'm doing is it considered to be a good design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a global variable :

```
 Context context = null;
```

Change Constructor to:

```
public CurrentGeolocation(Context context) { 
        buildGoogleApiClient(); 
        this.context = context;
        this.mCurrentGeolocationEntity = new CurrentGeolocationEntity();
    }
```

Now in calling Activity :

```
  CurrentGeolocation obj = new CurrentGeolocation(this);
```

or Fragment :

```
 CurrentGeolocation obj = new CurrentGeolocation(getActivity());
```

Comment: one and only! Passing Activity's context via constructor is highly recommended and a good practice.  Accept it answer if it works for you.

Comment: Good practice as long as your class is instantiated from your Activity and dies with it when the Activity is destroyed.