# android get context from another java class

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to get context from ocrgraphic.java file which is a helper.

How can I do?

1st activity

```
public final class OcrCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

2nd java

```
public class OcrGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {
```

I need to have application context in 2nd java file

Comment: Please do research before asking questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get Context in non-Activity class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917968/get-context-in-non-activity-class)

Comment: read before post , its vice versa

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OcrGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {
    private Context mContext;

    public OcrGraphic(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in OcrCaptureActivity:

```
...

OcrGraphic mOcrGraphic = new OcrGraphic(this);

...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context in `OcrGraphic` Constructor.