# What's the difference between 'this' and 'getActivity()'?

Tags: android

I have an idea they both get the 'context' so that functions know how they fit into the scheme of things, is this right?

Any clues for the evolving ape?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-fragment/8215398?s=1|1.9530#8215398

Comment: If you need to ask this question, you really need to spend more time learning the language you're writing and less time copy pasting from tutorials.

Comment: Why is this question so heavily down voted? I gave you an up vote because your question led me to a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the current class you are. It can be an `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Adapter`, `View`, etc. And when you use it what you are doing is just passing a reference of the current object of that class.

Let's say you are working on a custom `View`. Anywhere in the code of that view where you call `this` will be interpreted as the View itself, so the value of `this` changes depending on what class you are.

The method `getActivity()` is defined only in the `Fragment` class and any other class extending `Fragment` and this method returns and Object of the type `Activity`.

On Android development is very common mixing those two because most of the applications code is in `Activity` classes, and calling `this` on an `Activity` class will return an `Activity` object but as you can see they are not the same thing.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)