# Storing Activity context in Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-context

I am using static factory method to create fragment. But I need to use activity's context in the fragment and therefore I need to wrap that context into a bundle and attach it to the fragment using setArguements() method so that I can retrieve it later.

But if I try to store context by doing bundle.putSerializable("tag", context) -> it throws an error. Can anyone tell me how to wrap activity context into a bundle?

Comment: Why man.. Why you can not use `getActivity()` method in your Fragment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I need to use activity's context in the fragment

You do not need it in most cases. All you need is to use `getActivity()` in your fragment instead.

Comment: does that mean we never need to pass any context to a fragment because it can always be obtained through getActivity()?

Comment: @allstraws see this question on how to get context in a fragment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-fragment

Comment: @allstraws you cannot get it always (i.e. you won't get it in your `getInstance()` implementation or constructor), but you basically need activity only when you are part of it, and in such case `getActivity()` is what you are looking for.