# Android: Fragment's new getContext() method is which context?

Tags: android, fragment

The docs for `Fragment.getContext()` says it

> returns the context the Fragment is currently associated with.

It was introduced in api 23
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()

Is this the `Application` or `Activity` `Context`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-fragment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**

`Fragment.getContext()` return the context of activity where fragment is used

**Details**

Since api 23 in `Fragment` class was introduced `mHost` field

```
// Activity this fragment is attached to.
FragmentHostCallback mHost;
```

And `Fragment.getContext()` uses it for getting context:

```
/**
 * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
 */
public Context getContext() {
    return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
}
```

There are several steps before you get Activity's context in fragment's `getContext()` method.

1) During Activity's initialization `FragmentController` is created:

```
final FragmentController mFragments = FragmentController.createController(new HostCallbacks());
```

2) It uses `HostCallbacks` class (inner class of `Activity`)

```
class HostCallbacks extends FragmentHostCallback<Activity> {
    public HostCallbacks() {
        super(Activity.this /*activity*/);
    }
...
}
```

3) As you can see `mFragments` keep the reference to the activity's context.

4) When the application creates a fragment it uses `FragmentManager`. And the instance of it is taken from `mFragments` (since API level 23)

```
/**
 * Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
 * with this activity.
 */
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return mFragments.getFragmentManager();
}
```

5) Finally, the `Fragment.mHost` field is set in `FragmentManager.moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle, boolean keepActive)` method.

Comment: Frustrating as hell. The most useful method introduced in android in a long time, but requires API 23, which means any serious project is unlikely to use it for at least a few more years.

Answer (score 0):

As for FragmentActivity and inherited - 'getContext()' still will return activity context, you may see this if you'll check a source code.

Comment: You are correct, but the question is asking about the new `Fragment#getContext()`, not about `FragmentActivity#getContext()`.

Comment: I was talking about  `Fragment#getContext()`