# How do I get the activity that my fragment is in?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to use my database adapter in my list fragment to get all entities from a table to put into the listview, but when I try to construct it during the fragment creation I get the message that context can't be applied to my fragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(this); //error message here
    }
```

However, I don't get an error message when I put the adapter in my activity.

How can I get the activity that my fragment is in so I can use it as the context?
Or alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is a method `getActivity()` on `Fragment`. `DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(getActivity());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using context in fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-fragment)

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you get? That should be fleshed out; it seems like it might be something to do with context cannot be applied; but the way your question is formatted it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. You can get the activity your fragment is in by using:

```
getActivity();
```

Your code should be:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(getActivity()); // Replace this with getActivity()
}
```

Comment: Try not to store your Activity instance/reference for memory leak purposes.

Comment: That's just for example for his understanding. I have added what his actual code should have been. I personally never store the acticity instance.