# Argument this doesn´t work. [required: 'android.content.context'

Tags: android, android-context

I use this:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.action_bar));
```

To use colors from the color.xml .

It works great, but in some Codes it says:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.BaseFragment', required: 'android.content.Context'
```

But I import android.content.Context:

```
import android.content.Context;
```

I tried to use instead of 'this':

```
actionBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.action_bar));
```

But than Android Studio say :

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'context'
```

Comment: When you're in a fragment you cannot pass `this` for it's a Fragment, not an Activity and thus not a subtype of `Context`. Use `getContext()` instead.

Comment: A Fragment is not a Context

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

instead of

```
this
```

Comment: No than Android studio say : cannot resolve symbol: 'getActivity()'

Answer (score 2):

`Fragment` is not a subtype of `Context`.

When inside of a fragment use this:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.action_bar)
```

When inside an activity you can use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.action_bar)
```

Comment: Same like above. Android Studio say: Cannot resolve symbol: 'getContext()'

Comment: What's `org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.BaseFragment`? If it's a subclass of androids `Fragment` and you haven't messed with `getContext()` or `getActivity()` either should work. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
actionBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), 

R.color.action_bar));
```