# cannot resolve constructor for spinner adapter in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a tabbed activity "ActivityBeamRec" that has two fragments, in the second fragment error occur when i try to add spinner, here is the fragment code

```
public  class FragBeamRec extends Fragment  {

        public static FragBeamRec newInstance() {
        FragBeamRec fragment = new FragBeamRec();
        return fragment;
             }

        public FragBeamRec() {
    }
    static  EditText tasss = null;
    static EditText tass1 = null;
    static  Spinner spinAs = null;
    static Spinner spinAs1 = null;

    static  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_beam_rec, container, false);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(0,"");
        list.add(1,"");
        list.add(2,"");
        spinAs  = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinAs1 = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            spinAs.setAdapter(adapter);

            return v;
    }

}
```

I tried to use    `ActivityBeamRec.this`   insted of    `this`    but I ended with an error "ActivityBeamRec is not an enclosing class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

to

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

The param needs to be a context. Use `getActivity()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29

To the comment

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: it work thanks, but when i add    `spinAs.setOnItemSelectedListener(getActivity());`    gives an error, also if I put "this" wont work

Comment: @tamimabweini you need to set a selection listener with annonymous inner class or let your fragment class implement the listener and then use you use this. check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

to this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Comment: @tamim abweini see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will  [help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215398/3514144)

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```