# Using setAndroidContext(this) in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically i am new to the fragment, i have to connect my database with my fragment and for that i have to initialize my firebase context but it gives error under (this). Any alternative for that?

### CODE

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); //error
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using context in a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment does not have a `Context` by itself. You need to call

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());
```

Because Activity does have `context`. You can do so in `onAttach()` method, because the Fragment that's what's called when Fragment is actually attached to an Activity. Alternatively, you can leave it in `onCreate()` since it gets called **after** `onAttach()`. Check the [official documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) Might be useful for you to learn the order in which Fragment's methods are being called.

Comment: Thanks it works, if i want to do casting like use **findViewById** to save my text what should i do? i am currently using getView() but it's not working.

Comment: Well this is actually another matter. Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem. I can write you how you can use findViewById here but it will be ugly and in one line cause formatting in comments is different.

Comment: You need to do it in `onCreateView` method. Something like this `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_id, container, false);
        myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);`

Comment: Pay attention that this needs to be done in `onCreateView`. The easiest way to override methods in Android Studio is to click CTRL+O and start typing the name of the method and it'll find it for ya.