# Converting Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am converting an activity to a fragment so that I can use it within the Android Studio Navigation Drawer template.

I have changed all my activities to extend from fragment, and ensured that I am importing v4 support for fragments.

I have resolved most of the issues that Android Studio has raised...but I am really stuck on the final issue:

I have a fragment that used to be the mainActivity (now called liveview_fragment.java), which calls a class called ApplicationController in a file called ApplicationController.java.  However, the line in liveview_fragment that calls ApplicationController gives the following error:

[image: screenshot of error]

I am new to android/java, with most of my learning coming from tutorials and trial/error. Please could someone point out what I have missed in order to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error here directly please?

Comment: Your ApplicationController constructor expects an Activity, but you're passing a Fragment to it.

Comment: Also, please post some code, including the constructor for ApplicationController and the code where you create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to pass a context to the ApplicationController. Try with `getActivity()` or `getContext()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `liveview_fragment` is now a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`. In order to get the hosting `Activity`, you can call `getActivity()`. This will probably fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the getActivity() method to get the context of your attached activity, but always remember one thing: Fragments are slightly unstable and getActivity returns null some times, so for that, always check the isAdded() method of fragment before getting context by getActivity() refer [Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)