# Add context Array Adapter in fragment class

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i have a problem in android studio 
i want add context in array adapter in fragment class but this is not Acceptance 
this is image :

[image]

and use `getContext` but not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using context in a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)

Comment: Please do not post error messages and code samples as images, as it makes it more difficult for people having similar issues to find your question (and thus its answers).  Please copy and paste them directly into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do two things:

1. Initialize your `arrayList`, like: `arrayList = new ArrayList();`
2. Use `getActivity()` instead of `this` (like suggested by Ricardo Barroca below).

Hope this helps.