# Can a Fragment getContext() return null when isResumed() is returning true

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my code, I am displaying a `Toast` after a network request callback.

Since `Toast` requires a `Context`, I am first checking if the `Fragment` is in the resumed state `isResumed()` before doing the `getContext()` call inside the `Toast`.

I am getting `IllegalStateException` with `Fragment not attached to a context` error pointing to that line of code where I display the `Toast`

So my question is, how come `getContext()` can return null and the fragment is in the resumed state?

Note: As a solution I have added another `isAdded()` check.

Comment: *Can a Fragment getContext() return null when checking isResumed()* **Yes** if you activity is not attached with fragment in that case it will return `null`

Comment: @NileshRathod Well this is my point. I am checking if Fragment isResumed which means visible (resumed state). How can it be resumed and in the same time not attached to a context?

Comment: show your code, you probably did something wrong in it.

Comment: @TareKKhoury try to use [`onAttach(Context context)` to get `Context`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732620/7666442)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko nothing to share, pretty simple `if(isResumed())` check and display a `Toast` inside

Comment: @NileshRathod I have solved the error. My question is for me to understand how come getContext() is null while isResumed() returns true :)

Comment: yes, might be it returns null, I m suggesting that don't use ```getContext()```, use ```getActivity()``` instead

Comment: @Priyankagb They are the same. both return the Activity hosting the Fragment

Comment: How does the network callback get your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
public class yourFragment extends Fragment {
   Context context

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        super.onAttach(context);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.context = null;
   }
}
```