# Facebook banner, Interstitial and Rewarded ads load in fragment

Tags: android

This is Rewarded video ads code

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the Audience Network SDK
    AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);       
}
...
}
```

[Rewarded Video Ads in main activity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/rewarded-video)

in  fragment  **AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);**   not support

Comment: You forgot to ask question here .. Whats the Problem you are having with the code ?

Comment: See Duplicate [Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize it in every Activity/Fragment `AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);`

You can initialize it once and it will work everywhere.

From the official guide

> Before creating an ad object and loading ads, you should initialize
>   the Audience Network SDK. It is recommended to do this at app launch.

However if you still want to do in fragment. change context `this` to `getActivity()`
`AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(getActivity());`