# How to recreate activity

Tags: android, kotlin, activity-lifecycle, kotlin-lateinit

I have activity and fragment. I get shared pref. in my fragment:

```
   private var dManager: DataManager?=null
   private lateinit var sp: SharedPreferences
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?{
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test1_new_design, container, false)
    level = arguments!![Constants.LEVEL].toString()
    sp = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFERENCES, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    dManager = MyApp.gManager.getDataManager(sp,level,test)
```

And some times I get crash report that

```
lateinit property sp has not been initialized
```

I do not use sp before initialization, so it means `activity!!.getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFERENCES, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)` returns null.   Is it means that activity has been destroyed?

If I check that sp == null, what should I do futher in fragment? Restart app or recreate activity? What is the right way?

Comment: show full code please

Comment: if you are using `sp = activity!!.getSharedPreferences()` inside fragment then please don't use `activity/getActivity()` to get `Context` inside fragment because `activity/getActivity()` retuns `null`  if the your  `fragment` is not currently attached to a parent `activity`

Comment: @NileshRathod is correct, but it should have crashed if the activity is `null` and not let the rest of the code block to execute due to the `!!`. Please share a bigger code snippet, is the initialization right before passing the sharedPreferences around?

Comment: @Giorgos Neokleous I shared more code. There is no initialination before using sp. The crash happens in less than 0.5% cases. I think it can be connected with memory clearing, but I do not understand how to prevent this crash (what to do after checking sp and other lateinit properties)

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Thanks, but what should I do instead?

Comment: @Dima try to get `context` inside `fragment` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732620/7666442

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this would be calling:

```
if(!::sp.isInitialized) {
    sp = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFERENCES, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    dManager = MyApp.gManager.getDataManager(sp,level,test)
}
```

In the fragment onStart() method.