# what's the better way using context in fragment?

Tags: android

I have a Three choice to use context in fragment. The first one is using Fragment(context : Context). I think this way is not good because of dependency. The second is using getContext. In java I couldn't use getContext(),but In Kotlin I have known using context(getContext()) is possible(I don't understand why this is possible). And The Third is using GlobalApplicationContext. Which is the best way?

Comment: `Fragment(context : Context)` this will crash. `The Third is using GlobalApplicationContext` this is not themed. What's wrong with `.getActivity()`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity(), which returns the activity associated with fragment.
The activity is a context (since its extend context)
and also using GlobalAppContext is not recommended

Comment: And in Kotlin you can also use `requireActivitty()` or `requireContext()` to return a non-null version (instead these will throw an exception when the Fragment is not currently attached to an Activity).

Answer (score 0):

`view.context`
This is the view returned from onCreateView method.