# Fragment button with a link to a website doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to add a link to my created button which is on a fragment. This is currently what I have. I can get the button working if it's on the main activity but I don't know what to do from there.

java

```
public class RideSharesFragment extends Fragment {

    public RideSharesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ride_shares, container, false);
    }

    public void Uber(View view){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.uber.com/")
        );
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Ride_shares"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_`enter code here`constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lyft"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.203" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Uber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Uber"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`startActivity(Intent)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) is a method of `Context`. So you can use it by preparing `Context` instance using [`requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext()) or `getContext()` in a Fragment and invoke the method on the instance:

```
 requireContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Now it just crashes the app. 

public void Uber(View view){
        Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.uber.com/"));
        requireContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

Comment: @ChanCho Please show your error log.

Answer (score 0):

#### From fragment you should use:

#### Java:

##### `getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);`

#### Kotlin:

##### `activity?.startActivity(browserIntent)`

[Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)