# What should I change if this is in a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

The "this" in the two lines of this DailyMealFragment is having error. How could I change the "this" so that it could run in this DailyMealFragment

```
private fun loadRecyclerViewItems() {
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        binding.itemsRv.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        val itemList:ArrayList<RestaurantsModels> = ArrayList()

        for (i in titles.indices){
            val model = RestaurantsModels(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i])
            itemList.add(model)
        }

        val adapterItem = RestaurantsAdapter(this, itemList)
        binding.itemsRv.adapter = adapterItem
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())` do something like this. and for `adapter` create `val adapterItem by lazy { RestaurantsAdapter() }` on the top of your adapter class after imports

```
private fun loadRecyclerViewItems() {
    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    binding.itemsRv.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    val itemList:ArrayList<RestaurantsModels> = ArrayList()

    for (i in titles.indices){
        val model = RestaurantsModels(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i])
        itemList.add(model)
    }
    binding.itemsRv.adapter = adapterItem
}
```