# Android Application class method onCreate being called multiple times

Tags: lifecycle, acra, android

i've overloaded the Application class in my android app and i'm using the [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) report system.
My app looks like ( [real source code here](https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/blob/master/src/it/evilsocket/dsploit/DSploitApplication.java) ) :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        ACRA.init( this );

        /*
         * Initialize my singletons etc
         * ...
         * ...
         */
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And as far as i know, the Application object should be created only once, so the onCreate method should be called only once.
The problem is, that in my crash reports ( from ACRA ) i have this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service it.evilsocket.myapp.net.N ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service it.evilsocket.myapp.net.NetworkMonitorService: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once**
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2283)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:495)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2269)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once
    at org.acra.ACRA.init(ACRA.java:118)
    at it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:46)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:492)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:495)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2269)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once
    at org.acra.ACRA.init(ACRA.java:118)
    at it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:46)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:492)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ACRA#init called more than once
    at org.acra.ACRA.init(ACRA.java:118)
    at it.evilsocket.myapp.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:46)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:492)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2269)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So it seems like the app onCreate is being called multiple times, any idea on this ?

**NOTES:**

- In my android xml manifest, i did **NOT** use the
  android:process="string" attribute.
- Yes, **i'm sure** that in my initialization routines i'm **not** accidentally
  calling MyApplication.onCreate .

Comment: I'm not talking about Activity.onCreate ( which is normally being called every time a configuration change occurs ), but Application.onCreate!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint here?

Comment: it's something i can't reproduce on my device, i just see this from the ACRA reports ... if i break there or put a Log.d, onCreate is called only once on both my smartphone and tablet.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the referenced question. The referenced question is about Activity.onCreate() whereas here is about Application.onCreate(). Answers can't be merged.

Comment: How did u solve this issue ?

Comment: In my case, onCreate method of application class is only being called when I install the app in mobile, it does not being invoked every time when I kill the app and restart it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace, it looks like `ACRA.init` is calling `makeApplication`. I suspect that there's some sort of code to check if the application has been created already and if not, create it and that it is caused by your calling `ACRA.init` before `super.onCreate`. Generally when overriding `onCreate` methods (whether `Application` or `Activity`) it's recommended to call `super.onCreate` as the first line of your implementation and do your custom stuff afterwards. I'd give that a shot and see if it fixes things.

Comment: That could be an explanation. I documented ACRA with an init before super.onCreate() in order to let ACRA report exceptions that would happen as soon as possible in the application creation process. I might reconsider this if this behavior is reported by more users.

Comment: @KevinGaudin - I've tried Acra with init after super.onCreate(), and still get "ACRA#init called more than once" error from time to time

Comment: I can confirm that even if you call ACRA.init() after super(), this issue still happens.

Comment: agree with you, @AswinKumar

Answer (score 33):

I think that you have additional process in your application. That is why Application.onCreate is called more than once. Look into your manifest file and try to find the activity or service with something like **android:process=** . This means that activity/service is starting in second Dalvik VM, and that's why another application instance is created.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also seeing this with ACRA 4.4.0 in the wild.

Perhaps something as simple as this under the init method?

```
if (mApplication != null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("ACRA#init called more than once");
    //(return or finish or gracefully exit somehow)       
} else {
    mApplication = app;
    //and then continue with rest of acra init...
```

Edit: 12/27/12 As a follow up to this, it looks like Kevin has adopted these changes.  Details are here:  https://github.com/ACRA/acra/commit/cda06f5b803a09e9e7cc7dafae2c65c8fa69b861

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at ACRA source code recently and think this issue has been addressed in ACRA in two ways:

1. Instead of onCreate(), now ACRA's doc recommends initializing ACRA
   in attachBaseContext which is called before onCreate().
2. ACRA does have some logic to check if there are other ACRA instances
   during the initialization. If yes, ACRA will unregister the existing
   reporter and bypass the current reporter by some Proxy treatment.

Check init function in [ACRA.kt](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/acra-core/src/main/java/org/acra/ACRA.kt)