# How can Android Application get initialized more than once in the main process?

Tags: java, android, linux, jvm, startup

Is it possible that Application.onCreate() get called more than once in the main process of the app? I saw a lot of those happens on Android 7.0 on my app but couldn't figure out any scenario that might happen. Please help!!!

Comment: Here's what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809737/android-application-class-method-oncreate-being-called-multiple-times

Comment: We could guess all day about what could be happening, but posting your code could eliminate most of the guessing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does Application's onCreate() method get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7686482/608639)